# How to perform the following deduction symbolically?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

$$i \frac{d}{dt}a_n = (a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}) + |a_n|^2 (a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}), \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

In the above, $a_n := a_n(t)$. Consider $P = \sum\limits_{n}g(|a_n|^2)$ where $g$ is some function to be determined from the balancing of the equation $\frac{d}{dt}P = 0$. By chain-rule, we have $$i\sum\limits_{n}g'(|a_n|^2)(\frac{d}{dt}\Big [a_n\Big ] a_{n}^{*}- a_{n}\frac{d}{dt} \Big [ a_{n}^{*}\Big ])=0$$

After substituting the ODE into the above expression, we should arrive at $\ln(1+|a_n|^2)$. Can Mathematica perform the following, symbolically?

1. Chain-rule manipulation,
2. Substitution of the ODE,
3. Finally, arrival at deducing $g = \ln(1+|a_n|^2)$

Parts $1$ and $2$ can both be done I think, but deducing that $g = \ln(1+|a_n|^2)$ is what I am at a loss on.

Comment: Derivative in respect to `t` of something that is independent on `t` is zero. So your formulas makes no sense to me. Also what is the purpose of `i` in front of the sum? The left side of equation is equal to zero so `i` is irrelevant there.

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect that $a_n$, $a_{n\pm 1}$ are functions of $t$. The $i$ comes from substituting the ODE into $\frac{d}{dt}a_n$ and $\frac{d}{dt}a_{n}^{*}$ respectively.

Comment: $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ but if `n=1` then in the first formula you have $a_{1-1}=a_{0}$. What is that $a_{0}$?

Comment: Another function of $t$. This is a system of ODEs